# How to specify schema location for changelog tables

Tags: postgresql, gradle, liquibase

Is there a way to specify the schema where liquibase creates the database changelog tables (databasechangelog and databasechangeloglock)?

I'm using postgresql and gradle. I defined a schema for my application (e.g. myapplication).

When I run the liquibase update task from gradle, the application specific tables are correctly created inside the 'myapplication' schema, but the liquibase changelog stuff is created in the 'public' schema.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not covered in the documentation, but available in current versions of Liquibase (I'm not sure how far back that applies) are the command line arguments

```
--liquibaseCatalogName
```

and

```
--liquibaseSchemaName
```

Using these will allow you to keep your "managed schema" and your "liquibase schema" separate.

For gradle, I think you would specify these in you configuration block:

```
liquibase {
  activities { 
    main {
      changeLogFile 'changelog.groovy'
      url 'jdbc:h2:db/liquibase_workshop;FILE_LOCK=NO'
      username 'sa'
      password ''
      changeLogParameters([ myToken: 'myvalue',
                            second: 'secondValue'])
      liquibaseSchemaName 'myLiquibaseSchema'
      defaultSchemaName   'myApplicationSchema'
    }
    second {
      changeLogFile 'second.groovy'
      url 'jdbc:h2:db/liquibase_workshop;FILE_LOCK=NO'
      username 'sa'
      password ''
      changeLogParameters([ myToken: 'myvalue',
                            second: 'secondValue'])
    }
  }

  // runList = project.ext.runList
  // runList = 'main'
  runList = 'main, second'
}
```

If you are using a properties file, the properties you set are the same names as the command line options, so you would have something like this:

```
liquibaseSchemaName=myLiquibaseSchema
```

Comment: How can I instruct Liquibase to create the `liquibaseSchemaName`?

Comment: Liquibase does not currently have a command that can create a new schema.

Comment: how can i do this with java ? in the property file ? i want to separate my model schema from the liquibase tables schema

Comment: Edited to add section on properties file.

Comment: "Liquibase does not currently have a command that can create a new schema" - which is dumb, at best. I can't understand the hype for this tool, when it missed such a basic feature

Comment: @Eugene pull requests are always welcome. Perhaps after you've had a go at implementing it you will understand why it was not implemented.

Comment: @SteveDonie agree, I am biased because I want such a feature. But there were many other things that were broken anyway. We just went with cobliteam, that had everything we hoped for.